# Unify the colors of a raster - from satellite imagery

Tags: qgis, raster, color

I'm performing analyses based on pixel values on a Raster, which is a satellite image from 2014 (.tif format). This satellite image is exported from Google Earth and georeferenced in QGIS.

The differences that we see in the picture bellow, is the result of the merging of several satellite images, by Google.

[image: Diff_color_sat]

Do you know a way to unify the color on this image, in order to get the same color of water / vegetation etc. ?

I tried with the Semi-Automatic Classification module, I didn't get a good result. I would also like to keep the natural colors.

When I try to play with the colors, the vegetation at the bottom right appears the same color as the water at the top left.

[image: Mod_colors]

Comment: You need to do the colour balancing *before* you merge/mosaic to a single raster.

Comment: This image is georeferenced from Google Earth. The result is one raster with the 3 RGB bands.  I didn't merge any raster before, this operation was made by the services of Google. (I updated my post).

Comment: Then no, not possible.  Well, I suppose you could try clipping each individual original image, colour balancing them individually, then re-merging but I don't know how successful that would be...

Comment: What satellite is it, can you find the original data and download it?

Comment: Image Landsat / Copernicus (given the definition, it must be Landsat). I think I can download it on EarthExplorer.

Comment: Well, I didn't find it.